# Cannot write output after reading input; Experiencing this but not certain of cause

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, protocolexception

I am experiencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413028/cannot-write-output-after-reading-input) problem although not sure if exactly.

I have discovered `Cannot write output after reading input` in logs and, per the above, I believe this is occurring because of a `getResponseCode()` followed by a `getOutputStream()`.

Would this be the cause of the logged error I am seeing?

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

if(conn.getResponseCode() == 0){
    logger.debug("Success");
} else {                 
    logger.debug("Time out set for 30 seconds");
}
String input = writer.getBuffer().toString();
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
```

Comment: Where is your code? Can you post a snippet around the lines that are throwing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    
String pushURL = "Your URL";
    
URL url = new URL(pushURL);
    
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/restService");
    
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
    
if(conn.getResponseCode() == 0){
     logger.debug("Success");
} else {                 
 logger.debug("Time out set for 30 seconds");
}
    
String input = writer.getBuffer().toString();
    
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

os.write(input.getBytes());
    
os.flush();
```

will result in a `java.net.ProtocolException` because of the following located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413028/cannot-write-output-after-reading-input):

> The HTTP protocol is based on a request-response pattern: you send your   request first and the server responds. Once the server responded, you can't send any more content, it wouldn't make sense. (How could the server give you a response code before it knows what is it you're trying to send?)
>
> So when you call server.getResponseCode(), you effectively tell the server that your request has finished and it can process it. If you want to send more data, you have to start a new request.

Thus, the OP is calling `conn.getOutputStream();` after `conn.getResponseCode()` which is generating the `java.net.ProtocolException` whose `Exception.getMessages()` yields

> Cannot write output after reading input